# Detecting the remaining lifetime of an ssh-agent identity

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent

The `ssh-add` command lets you specify the lifetime of an identity being added to `ssh-agent`. For example, if I type

```
ssh-add -t 1h
```

the identify will expire after 1 hour. I can then list the identities currently represented by the agent using `ssh-add -l`.

Is there a way (other than recording information when I run the `ssh-add` command) to determine the remaining lifetime of an identity? If not, is there some security-related reason why there *shouldn't* be a way to get this information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no interface in ssh-agent communication protocol to provide this information. It is used only when adding the key (`constraint` array), but this is not returned when you list the keys, as the [PROTOCOL.agent](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/PROTOCOL.agent#n372) page describes (there is only key blob and comment for each key).

Requiring this would probably require to change the protocol, which is a run for a long distance.